# MySQL Query Priority on two AND statements

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here is an excerpt of the code that I'm currently working:

Assuming that `$product=Onion` & `$area=Bulua`.

```
$crop_query = $db->query(
                    "SELECT Crop, Price, DateUpdated, Area FROM crops 
                    WHERE Crop = '{$product}' 
                    AND `DateUpdated` = (SELECT max( `DateUpdated` )FROM crops WHERE Crop = '{$product}' ) 
                    AND `Area` = '{$area}'");

                    $result = $crop_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); 
                    $message = "The current price of {$result->Crop} is P{$result->Price}/kg, as of {$result->DateUpdated} in {$result->Area} Market.";            
echo $message;
```

Excerpt of the SQL Table:

```
Crop    ID  Price   DateUpdated             Area
Onion   1   75      2011-01-26 14:30:00     Cogon
Onion   2   200     2012-02-22 14:30:00     Bulua
```

The code above will then successfully print the desired output which is:

"The current price of **Onion** is **P200**/kg, as of **2012-02-22 14:30:00** in **Bulua** Market."

However it throws an error when I change the value of $area to `$area = Cogon`. I noticed that it's priority is only on the `DateUpdated` instead of `Area` AND `DateUpdated`.

EDIT: as to clarify the comments below

- The whole thing works except when I change the value of $area from
  `Bulua` to `Cogon`.
- The error is:  Trying to get property of non-object. Which I probably due to the `DateUpdated` being prioritized on the query

---

It's now currently working. Thanks for the concern guys. :)
I'll post another answer when I can.

Comment: What is the error it throws?

Comment: Can you please provide more info abt the error?

Comment: *"...when I change the value of $Area to $Area = Cogon"* - change it where? And btw, `$Area` is not the same as `$area` which you posted both lettercase types.

Comment: It just says 'Trying to get property of non-object' which was the result of the DateUpdated priority.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: When I change the value of $Area from 'Bulua' to 'Cogon' 
EDIT: yes I know, just a typo :)

Comment: And why use this format `$result->Crop`? You're trying to call what should be a pre-defined method.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: The whole thing works unless I change the Area.

Comment: maybe $result is not an object. var_dump() it and see what it is for 2nd case.

Comment: @Grish Yes, the result is not an object because the fetched array is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your data and your query. `$result` will be `false` if no rows are returned, so you can't do `$result->Crop`.

You should do something like this:

```
$result = $crop_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
if ($result) {
  // Returned results, do something ...
}
```

Also, consider simplifying your query to this:

```
SELECT Crop, Price, DateUpdated, `Area`
  FROM crops 
  WHERE Crop = '{$product}' 
  AND `Area` = '{$area}'
  ORDER BY DateUpdated DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @Dahh, I updated my answer with a simplified query too. Hope it helps.

Comment: Oh god, I never thought about LIMIT (another facepalm.jpg). Thanks again :D